# How to use JMH with gradle?

Tags: gradle, jmh

I want to use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), an OpenJDK microbenchmark tool, with **gradle**. However, Im getting the NPE on compilation. On the other hand, JMH works when using from maven.

I am not posting any `build.gradle` as it is basic - apply java plugin and add dependency on JHM tool (`org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-core:0.2`).

I have tried whats written [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/2013-August.txt) without success.

What else I have to do? I think something with setting the agent, but I still didnt figure it out.

Exception:

```
:compileJava
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openjdk.jmh.processor.internal.GenerateMicroBenchmarkProcessor.validMethodSignature(GenerateMicroBenchmarkProcessor.java:502)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just finished my "[masterpiece](https://gist.github.com/mrbald/7bbb5113c3164d5243314da8c28649a1)". No uber-jars, no plugins, code base separated from main & test, benchmarks compilation hooked to main, but does not run automatically in the mainstream lifecycle. Simple, explicit, and hackable, vanilla gradle.

I run it directly from IntelliJ, to run on a box you probably will need the uber-jar back :-)

Before doing it I have spent a fair amount of time trying to get that plugin work, but it's way too clunky for my taste.

Step-by-step breakdown below.

**Define a new `sourceSet` called `jmh` with classpath hooked to that of the main `sourceSet`**

```
sourceSets {
    jmh {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/jmh/java']
        scala.srcDirs = ['src/jmh/scala']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/jmh/resources']
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}
```

**Define dependencies for it (at minimum JMH and its annotation processor).**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    jmhImplementation 'org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-core:1.35'
    jmhImplementation 'org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-generator-annprocess:1.35'
}
```

**Define a task `jmh` of type `JavaExec`**

```
task jmh(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: jmhClasses) {
    main = 'org.openjdk.jmh.Main'
    classpath = sourceSets.jmh.compileClasspath + sourceSets.jmh.runtimeClasspath
}
```

**Hook `jmhClasses` task to run after `classes` to make sure benchmarks are compiled with the rest of the code**

```
classes.finalizedBy(jmhClasses)
```

Comment: So simple. Perfect! One thing that I ran across: you need to ensure that you've configured IntelliJ to [use separate module per source set](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html), otherwise it will not find your JMH source sets.

Comment: I would only add the requirement of `jmhAnnotationProcessor 'org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-generator-annprocess:1.35'` in the dependencies.

Answer (score 27):

Currently you can just use dedicated plugin [jmh-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/melix/jmh-gradle-plugin)

It requires minimal configuration and allows you to run JMH benchmarks as well as build benchmarks artifact

Comment: no possibility to run individual tests, no possibility to use separate jvm_args per test, etc. If you just want to "play" with JMH - sure, if you plan to be serious about it - this is a big NOGO.

Comment: It looks like the plugin now can be configured to run individual tests, use separate JVM args etc. See the [configuration options](https://github.com/melix/jmh-gradle-plugin#configuration-options).

Comment: In addition to the configuration options (described above), it's also possible to tweak a lot of these things through JMH's annotations. You can also run `./gradlew jmhJar` in your project and then use the JMH cli as you would with a JMH jar file built with maven. e.g. `java -jar build/libs/my-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jmh.jar MySpecificBenchmarkClass $insertYourFavoriteOptionsHere`. Seems to me the gradle plugin has all the bells & whistles a maven project would.

Answer (score 10):

My bad, I was trying to benchmark a method that has an argument - of course JMH will not know what to pass :) Once when I created a void method with no arguments, everything worked.

My `build.gradle`:

```
defaultTasks 'build'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'shadow'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name 'Shadow'
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/content/johnrengelman/gradle-plugins'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle.plugins:shadow:0.7.4'
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.openjdk.jmh.Main'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


build.doLast {
    tasks.shadow.execute()
}

shadow {
    outputFile = new File('build/libs/microbenchmarks.jar')
}

ext {
    lib = [
        ... other dependencies...
        jmh:            'org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-core:0.2'
    ]
}

dependencies {
    compile lib... other dependencies...
    compile lib.jmh
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
```

Build tests and jar:

```
gw clean build
```

and then run them with:

```
java -jar build/libs/microbenchmarks.jar ".*" -wi 2 -i 10 -f 2 -t 16
```

### UPDATE

From recent versions of JMH, you would also need to add dependency to:

```
org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-generator-annprocess:0.5.4
```

and you can use shadow 0.8.

Comment: Yeah, but also JMH should have printed more sane error message. Can you try to feed the erroneous benchmark you had before to 1.0-SNAPSHOT version of jmh (requires building from source)? I have rebuilt the significant part of the validation code there.

Comment: Yeah, NPE was confusing to me, I thought I did something wrong. Sure, I will try 1.0-SNAPSHOT but have first to prepare everything with online repo, for other ppl. After that I can play with local.

Answer (score 6):

I made a very small example project to clone and modify as you like. It's a full working example:
https://gitlab.com/barfuin/jmh-gradle-example

It requires no shadow Jars and no plugins, while still running the benchmark in a dedicated JVM. The project also includes some extra Gradle tasks for printing the classpath, the JMH options, etc., stuff that may help to understand what's going on.

Comment: It's a lot of boilerplate that can be avoided by using the JMH Gradle plugin.

Comment: It's quite lean, no plugin, not much code either. Take a look!

Comment: I’ve already looked at it, and have come to the conclusion posted above. IMO, there’s no need to reinvent the wheel because “no plugin” isn’t necessarily an advantage here.

Comment: Well, [9 lines of code](https://gitlab.com/barfuin/jmh-gradle-example/-/blob/5a68fb2d847d9bfd9bf85abf76f5d01f71a522e4/build.gradle#L52-69) achieve the result, without a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you're an IntelliJ user, perhaps the easiest way to make it work, without all that workarounds, is to use the IDE plugin:

https://github.com/artyushov/idea-jmh-plugin

- Add the dependencies
- Create your benchmark
- be happy :)