# How do you relocate JMH Generated directories in gradle subprojects?

Tags: gradle, build, gradle-kotlin-dsl, jmh, generated-code

Trying to relocate generated sources for JMH build under kotlin gradle with melix/jmh-gradle-plugin

From :
.../projectroot/**SUBPRJ_A**/**BUILD**/jmh-generated-sources/...

To :
.../projectroot/**BUILD**/subProjects/**SUBPRJ_A**/jmh-generated-sources/...

I've tried a number of things including...

-- gradle.build.kts --

```
id("me.champeau.gradle.jmh") version "0.5.2"

... other irrelevant stuff ...

subprojects {

    this.setBuildDir(subPrjBuildDir)

    ... other irrelevant stuff ...

    idea {
        module {
            iml { setGenerateTo(rootIdeaOutFolder) }
            val subIdeaOutFolderRoot = rootIdeaOutFolder.resolve(subPrjExtPath)
            setOutputDir(subIdeaOutFolderRoot.resolve("main"))
            setTestOutputDir(subIdeaOutFolderRoot.resolve("test"))
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        this.jmh {
            java.setSrcDirs(mutableListOf(subRoot.resolve("perf/java"),subRoot.resolve("main/java")))
            java.setOutputDir(rootPrjDir.resolve("build/subProject/${subPrj.name}"))
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle 6.6.1
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 (Community Edition)

Comment: I do not know if it helps you, but I stopped using this plugin, an instead use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53889428/1059372). You can look [here](https://github.com/wind57/0x-github-jmh-runner/blob/master/build.gradle) if you want..

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna try that just as soon as I get a different question answered... and then ill come back and update.  I like the idea of dropping the plugin.