# How to use JMH in Gradle with Kotlin DSL

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, jmh

My question is similar to [How to use JMH with gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443997/how-to-use-jmh-with-gradle), only with one caveat that I use Gradle Kotlin DSL. I also found this article https://arbitrary-but-fixed.net/java/algorithms/2019/09/29/jmh-gradle-config.html, but it unfortunately does not work when I have multiple subprojects. I have to define the tasks dependencies for each subproject for the @Benchmark annotation to be recognized. Just by simply adding the JMH-related dependencies with the `allprojects{}` closure at root project will strangely result in `unresolved reference: implementation` for the subprojects.

Let's say that I have one root project with 2 subprojects, each of them just benchmarking Hello World. Can anyone help me defining the `build.gradle.kts` and possibly the `settings.gradle.kts` for all projects?

I use OpenJDK 17 with Gradle 7.4.2